# Html.EditorFor set initial value of textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Binding to a view model in MVC3, using C#.

Having difficulty setting the initial value of the textbox, trying to do so without having to create a template etc

Any ideas or do I have to go down the path of creating a customn template?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set initial values in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        MyProperty = "initial value"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProperty)
```